# Working with pagination in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use pagination in an android project.There are 60 pieces of data which i want to display 10 at a time in a listview.But the problem is i am getting duplicates in the list that loads, i.e the first 10 are followed by the same 10 again:

The code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    public HttpResponse video_respons;
    public String video_string_response1;
    public ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs_Video;
    ArrayList<Ice_data> ice_list;
    String URL="http://footballultimate.com/icebucket/index.php/api/getVideo";
    String URL1="http://footballultimate.com/icebucket/index.php/api/getVideoByLimit";
    JSONObject jsonobj;
    JSONArray jsonarr;
    Ice_data iceobj;
    CustomIceAdapter ciadp;
    ListView list;
    int start = 1;
     int limit = 10;
     boolean loadingMore = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();
        // GEt all Data for Video
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(VideoActivity.this);
        Config.isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (!Config.isInternetPresent) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoActivity.this);
            // Shuld be fail icon
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage("Connection Not Available !" + "\n"
                    + "Please enable your Internet Connection");
            builder.setTitle("INTERNET CONNECTION");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            new GetVideos().execute();
        }
        // Get all Data for Video
         list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videoList);
        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;   
                   if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){    

                       new GetVideos().execute();
                   }

            }
        });
    }

    class GetVideos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private HttpResponse vip_respons;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            loadingMore = true;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL1);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start",String.valueOf(start)));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit",String.valueOf(limit)));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                video_respons = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                //video_string_response1 = getResponseBody(video_respons);
                video_string_response1=responsetostring.getResponseBody(video_respons);
                //Log.d("Store_Response", the_string_response1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String video_string) {
            try{
                   if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                       pDialog.dismiss();
                   }  
            }
          catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally
          {
              pDialog.dismiss();
          }
            if (video_string_response1!=null) {
                //displayjsonstring();
                geticevalues(video_string_response1);

            }
        }
    }
    public void geticevalues(String result)
    {

        try {
            jsonobj=new JSONObject(result);
            //ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();
            jsonarr=jsonobj.getJSONArray("video_data");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jso=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                iceobj=new Ice_data();
                iceobj.title=jso.getString("title");
                iceobj.image_URL=jso.getString("image");
                iceobj.video_URL=jso.getString("url");
                ice_list.add(iceobj);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ciadp=new CustomIceAdapter(VideoActivity.this,ice_list);
        ciadp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadingMore = false;
        list.setAdapter(ciadp);
        start+=10;
    }
```

The start and limit are the values which show the starting and the number of items in each request.I have also increamented the start value as `start+=10`.I am passing the start and limit values to the webservice in the async class.

Is there a more elegant way to do the above?Or can you fix  the above code.Please help!!

Comment: Is start value and return data corrent when requesting new data?

Answer (score 0):

initialization of ice_list inside doInBackground will eliminate duplicates

protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            loadingMore = true;

```
        ice_list=new ArrayList<Ice_data>();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {......................
```

Comment: That didnt fix the problem..If you say new keyword on each call of the webservice then wouldnt the old data inside it be wiped out and the list would start as a fresh one...

Comment: I am not sure its good to do this line  ciadp=new CustomIceAdapter(VideoActivity.this,ice_list); before this line see this tutorial it works for me http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/